# zsh vs bash when command not found options

Tags: bash, zsh

When I run the following in `bash`:

```
$ java
Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless  # version 11.0.13+8-0ubuntu1~20.04, or
sudo apt install default-jre              # version 2:1.11-72
sudo apt install openjdk-13-jre-headless  # version 13.0.7+5-0ubuntu1~20.04
sudo apt install openjdk-16-jre-headless  # version 16.0.1+9-1~20.04
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre-headless  # version 17.0.1+12-1~20.04
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless   # version 8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~20.04
```

However, in zsh, I just get:

```
$ java
zsh: command not found: java
```

How to make `zsh` also offer installation options like bash?

Comment: Note that what you see in `bash` isn't from `bash` itself, but an `apt`-based implementation of the `command_not_found_handle` hook. `zsh` provides a similar hook, `command_not_found_handler`.

Answer (score 0):

The [command-not-found](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/command-not-found) package provides this functionality.

From its README:

> To use it in bash, please add the following line to your .bashrc file:
> . /etc/bash_command_not_found
>
> To use it in zsh, please add the following line to your .zshrc file: .
> /etc/zsh_command_not_found                                 Note that
> it overrides the preexec and precmd functions, in case you have
> defined your own.